# How to open an .exe file by using class in python?

Tags: python, class, subprocess

I am writing a script in which i am trying to open an .exe file by using class and prints the process id.It looks as follows:

```
import subprocess
DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008
class hello:
    def open_exe(self,file):
        self.file = file
        print "file name",self.file
        process = subprocess.Popen([r"self.file"],creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS,shell=True)
        if object.pid is None:
            return 0
        else:
            print "Process id is: ", process.pid
            return 1
hello1 = hello()
hello1.open_exe("D:\\development\\learning\\score\\testing.exe")
```

When i run it does not open the file "testing.exe" but the process id does get printed.So, help me out why the specified .exe is not getting opened .If i pass the complete path of exe directly to the function "open_exe()" it does gets opened, but i want to open in the same manner as in code. So , kindly suggest appropriate solution.

Comment: learn the difference between `self.file` and `r"self.file"` in Python.

Comment: This can hardly work... what is `object`?

Comment: @ikaros45 Object is "hello1" the second last line of the code. Is it not right?

Comment: I don't see `object` defined in any line of your `open_exe` method. There is a python built in called `object` and it does not have any `pid` attribute. I cannot see how this code can work.